# Magento 2 : Error during compilation

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile

I encountered an error on running  `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` on CLI

Error is :

```
  [Zend\Code\Exception\RuntimeException]
  No tokens were provided
```

How to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

After researching for some hours on this issue, I found the answer.

This issue occurs when there are any empty files inside our project folders.

Search those files using command.

```
grep -lr 'No tokens were provided' vendor/
```

You will see the results:

```
vendor/zendframework/zend-code/src/Scanner/ConstantScanner.php
vendor/zendframework/zend-code/src/Scanner/TokenArrayScanner.php
vendor/zendframework/zend-code/src/Scanner/MethodScanner.php
vendor/zendframework/zend-code/src/Scanner/PropertyScanner.php
vendor/zendframework/zend-code/src/Scanner/ClassScanner.php
if (!$this->tokens) {
        throw new \Zend\Code\Exception\RuntimeException('No tokens were provided');
    }
```

You can solve this by deleting those files using a command in CLI:

```
find ./ -size 0 -delete
```

OR

```
find ./ -type f -empty -delete
```

Now, Do run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` again. Hope it helps to those who encounter this issue again.